# execute stored procedure with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a stored procedure call updateLosingSelections

When I run

```
 call updateLosingSelections
```

directly on my mysql database the expected result occurs.

When I try to run it from a php page with pdo nothing happens, but equally there is no error thrown or displayed. Am I missing something obvious here? Here is my code for the php page.

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once('../connections/connection.php');
$sql_update_standings = 'call updateLosingSelections()';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_update_standings);
$sth->execute();
 ?>
```

Thanks guys.
DS

edit... in the end, I have put the sql that was in my stored procedure and just left it as sql code that is in the pdo statement. tearing my hair out wasn't good for me.

Comment: What you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting to have a table in my database update. As I say, it does if I run the "call updateLosingSelections" in the mysql db directly

Answer (score 0):

My first glaring question is why are you passing a $data array into the execute() when your updateLosingSelections() has no parameters?

Essentially:

```
//turn this
$sth->execute($data);

//into this
$sth->execute();


//or if you want to do this
$sth->execute($data);

//then make sure to do this
session_start();
include_once('../connections/connection.php');
$sql_update_standings = 'call updateLosingSelections(?,?)'; //two question marks as placement holders
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_update_standings);
$sth->execute($data('somedata','moredata')); //two pieces of data which will replace the two ? marks above
```

I recommend taking a look at the DB2 documentation, seems quite similar.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc%2Fdoc%2Ft0023502.html

Comment: ah... i cut and pasted from another pdo statement from before. that's shouldn't be there. thanks... but still failing :( no error message as before. going to try reconda's suggestion now.

Comment: This might be a silly question but is $sth being declared in the connection.php file? If so then is it successfully connecting?

Comment: no silly questions here, monkey! yes, the connection is fine. using is in lots of places. This is the only one that doesn't work :(

Comment: This question is of particular interest to me now because I am using stored procedures in my application and I fear mine might do the same thing lol. I might be just grasping at straws here but does call from call updateLosingSelections() need to be capitalized? is updateLosingSelections capitalized in all the right places? Would you be able to implement an isolated test using the mysqli functions? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php